# If I receive an SOS signal, what is the proper response?

Tags: cw, procedure, emergency

My 5-year old son loves sending out an SOS signal using a toy Morse code generator (wired, don't worry about false alarms for real authorities).

He has learned to send the SOS signal and was asking me to send a response to him to let him know that help is on the way.

What Morse code should I respond with in a real life situation when I hear a distress call on radio?

Comment: How about a real life story?  Here is one where the proper response was merely to call 911.  https://www.heraldnet.com/news/hiker-safe-with-help-of-ham-radio/

Comment: Brilliant! thank you so much for the link

Comment: I know he's only 5, but it would still be a good idea to tell him that either SOS or [Mayday](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday) radio transmissions must **only** be sent during a *genuine emergency involving aircraft or ships at sea*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distress_signal): "[distress signals] must only be used where there is grave and imminent danger to life. Otherwise, urgent signals such as pan-pan can be sent. Most jurisdictions have ***large* penalties for false, unwarranted or prank distress signals**". Those penalties are jail time and very large fines.

Comment: @MikeWaters Only those involving airplanes or ships at sea? I thought it was any situation where your life or others lives were in danger (where it could help at least). For example, if you're lost in the desert with limited supplies and you have a portable rig on you, would it not be appropriate to send SOS?

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson One might think so, but that is definitely not the case. The key here is *grave and [imminent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imminent) danger to life*. Governments take that as (for example) "Our ship is sinking fast!". Check out [SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOS) and [Mayday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday) Wikipedia articles. See [Pan-Pan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan-pan).

Comment: @MikeWaters I see. In that case, would it be appropriate if, say, you were surrounded by a forest fire that was closing in? That's the only other situation I can think of where it could be appropriate on land.

Comment: Maybe you could devise a callsign-ish variation of his name or initials and teach him to call CQ with that... then you could actually answer and have a little audio-buzzer QSO - probably simple, but if it's in terms of *patterns* rather than letters not necessarily implausible.

Comment: @Mike Waters absolutely! I do understand the difference and will make sure he knows about it as well.

Comment: Presumably, if its an emergency but not one involving an aircraft or ship at sea, then you have to be rescued by the police before they can arrest you?

Comment: My 1957 "Radio Amateur's Handbook" says QRRR is the proper emergency message for land distress signaling.

Comment: @MikeWaters I am interested also to your response to Duncan. Your initial response does not support "only air or sea", but rather it supports "only in grave and imminent danger." So what about the forest fire mentioned, or you find a hiker skewered by a piece of wood through the abdomen, bleeding  badly and immobile (I have heard of that happening before), or other grave and imminent threats to one or more people on land?

Comment: @Aaron Perhaps you're right. "A distress signal indicates that **a person or group of people, ship, aircraft, or other vehicle** is threatened by serious and/or imminent danger and requires immediate assistance.[1]:PCG D−3 Use of distress signals in other circumstances may be against local or international law. An urgency signal is available to request assistance in less critical situations.". That's from the Wikipedia article, but to be sure the appropriate US government document should be consulted. I would probably call mayday if I were in the situations you describe.

Comment: @Aaron I am sure that I read 'only planes or boats' somewhere. [This implies that](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday).

Comment: Tagging @DuncanXSimpson since he made the original question. Duncan, see Mike's response.

Comment: @MikeWaters Another consideration is how likely your signal is to receive attention. I think a majority know SOS is special and recognize the pattern. Personally, I'm still studying and have no license yet; I know very little. I was considering buying a handheld this year and playing with it (receive only, since unlicensed). I could recognize an SOS and called 911, but I'd not recognize the other signals you mention. So even if SOS is incorrect (not "grave/imminent-death" and/or on land), it might be preferable anyway just to maximize success. Something to think about.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're simulating the situation with non-transmitting equipment, you get the play the part of actual emergency agencies.  You'd start by asking the SOS caller to identify themselves (call sign, ship name, etc.) and give their location and the nature of the emergency.

Of course, unless your 5 year old knows a lot more Morse than just SOS, that's where the exchange will end -- but this is a good way to get him interested in learning the whole alphabet (if he hasn't), getting his speed up, learning prosigns, and so forth.

In a real life situation, the FCC says you should respond to the caller and ask what assistance is needed -- pretty much what you'll do in simulation with your son.  Find out what's the emergency, where the caller is located (latitude and longitude, map grid, or town and address), etc.

Comment: Thanks. Guy knows  ICAO phonetics and can easily identify himself as Mike Sierra Delta with Mayday Mayday Mayday.

Answer (score 6):

Since this is all for a bit of fun, you could respond with the typical Morse Code response to indicate that the last transmission was successfully received: R:

```
•-•
```

Some operators stylize this as two R's sent consecutively. You could also use your "Dad" call sign by appending "de DAD":

```
-••  •    -••  •-  -••
```

which means this transmission is "from Dad".

As others have pointed out, in a real situation the response would either be asking for clarifying information (e.g. a location or nature of emergency) or it would be a confirmation that help is on the way. If I were responding, I would end my transmission with "de W9IQ" to indicate my FCC assigned call.

Comment: How about *ACK*?

Comment: @HankyPanky "ACK" isn't typically used with Morse Code but it is only for fun so feel free. A more likely response for an amateur radio operator with either be the indicated "R" or "QSL" meaning message received.

Comment: Perfect. I will discuss R and QSL both with him. Its good to use those because they can someday be real useful for him in real life, as opposed to non standard phrases.

Answer (score 4):

First, let's be very clear that making a false distress call is a federal crime carrying sanctions of up to six years imprisonment, and a fine of $250,000.

Second, there is no commercial or maritime use of Morse now, so distress calls use "Mayday Mayday Mayday" at the beginning and end. You are extremely unlikely to hear a Morse distress call or need to respond to one. Maritime Morse stations stopped operation on July 12, 1999, almost twenty years ago.

When someone who is not a first responder or dispatcher receives a distress call, they need to start writing down information to forward to first responders. If they don't provide it, and they may be scared and not thinking straight, you need to interview them.

Be calm and clear. If a better-prepared station steps in to help, let them do it.

For a maritime distress call, collect this information. A land call would be similar. This is a script for the person making the call, so you would walk them through this.

First, write down the local time (your own clock). If you have UTC, use that.

- Distress signal "MAYDAY", spoken three times.
- The words "THIS IS", spoken once.
- Name of vessel in distress (spoken three times) and call sign or boat registration number, spoken once.
- Repeat "MAYDAY" and name of vessel, spoken once.
- Give position of vessel by latitude or longitude or by bearing (true or magnetic, state which) and distance to a well-known landmark such as a navigational aid or small island, or in any terms which will assist a responding station in locating the vessel in distress. Include any information on vessel movement such as course, speed and destination.
- Nature of distress (sinking, fire etc.).
- Kind of assistance desired.
- Number of persons onboard.
- Any other information which might facilitate rescue, such as length or tonnage of vessel, number of persons needing medical attention, color hull, cabin, masks, etc.
- The word "OVER"

From: https://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?pageName=mtBoater

You should practice copying text, including asking for repeats and phonetic spelling.

The best practice is participating in drills and public service events for your local ARES/RACES emergency communication group.

Here is a recorded VHF marine distress call. You can find more of these on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKHBWOXfGMM

For more information about maritime Morse, start with the Night of Nights, which runs maritime Morse one day per year on July 12.

https://www.nps.gov/pore/planyourvisit/events_nightofnights.htm

Answer (score 3):

To respond to a *received* Morse SOS by radio requires a transmit system and operator able to do that.

Normally a transmit station license issued by the appropriate regulating agency having jurisdiction for that receive location is required to operate such a transmitter.

If no such transmit capabilities are available, then relaying the details of the SOS message to an appropriate, emergency response organization is about the best recourse available.

Comment: Relative to licensing, it's worth noting that FCC explicitly permits anyone do whatever is necessary with whatever radio equipment they can access in order to save lives or property in an actual emergency.  License or no license, any band you can access that might get through, any mode your transmitter can emit.  *In an emergency*.

Comment: That is technically true, but not actually useful. First, 90+% of emergency calls are not life or property emergencies. Second, if you interfere with other official traffic, you may still be fined. Third, if you don't use your radio in non-emergency situations, you won't be able to use it well in emergencies. So the whole "non-licensed emergency" thing not useful for emergency preparation. Because it isn't "preparation". It is just buying a radio.

Answer (score 3):

I received such notification while listening on 2182 kHz and phoned the Coast Guard with the broadcast-in-blind details I copied.

Their Coast station told the ship in distress to call the commercial station that was copying them! I called the Coast Guard back to notify them that I couldn't respond and was not a maritime station.

Happy ending, ship met by coast guard, dewatering pumps delivered and ship pumped out in time to avert sinking, ship towed to nearest port.

Comment: Great answer, thank You!

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!